# Many-to-Many EF core with ApplicationUser

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between ApplicationUser and Reserve.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Reserves = new HashSet<Reserve>();
    }
    public bool IsProfessional { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Reserve> Reserves { get; set; }
}

public class Reserve
{

    public Reserve()
    {
        this.Usuarios = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Begin { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } //free , reserved, confirmed, canceled
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

But I cant add the migration

```
PM> Add-Migration user-reserve-relationship
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Reserves' of type 'ICollection<Reserve>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.
```

Anyway, the same relationship works well to others entities but not ApplicationUser.

Can I use ApplicationUser many-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the follow in ef core :
Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported.
So my question is closed.